# linux oops message, is memory address virtual or physical?

Tags: linux, memory

In this error message:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff8804c001fade
```

Is ffff8804c001fade the physical memory address or virtual memory address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a kernel virtual address, and if you're interested in what is supposed to be located there then you can look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt which says:

```
ffff880000000000 - ffffc7ffffffffff (=64 TB) direct mapping of all phys. memory
```

so your address should be mapped to the physical address 4c001fade, just a bit past the 19 gig mark. The most likely reason for it faulting is that the machine has less than 19 gigs of RAM.

Comment: Absolutely right, the machine has 16Gb. Any idea why it goes over the physical memory? The kernel does know how much physical memory there is, doesn't it? How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: The first three characters of the log message are the truth. It's a bug. Somehow a bad pointer was created. Hopefully you got a stack trace with that error message, which you can use to file a useful bug report. http://www.google.com/search?q=Linux+kernel+bug+reporting